# Changing all UILabels in a single view

Tags: xcode, ios, uilabel

Does anyone know if there's a way to change the background, border color, and other properties of all UILabels in a single view at once? I have a view with about 10 UILabels, and I want to change all of their backgrounds, border colors, border radii, and border widths. I'd rather not wire up all of the views and code each of the changes individually though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

for example your view instance is myView then you can do this as -

```
for (UIView *view in myView.subviews) 
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)view;
            // chenge here what you want to change
        }
    }
```